# How to display multiple data from a checkbox when checked?

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple checkboxes, I want to display an array of data when multiple checkboxes are clicked, but only one value is displayed, how to display an array ?What is the problem?

```
  <div class="form-group" >
                <h5>Your languages</h5>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @foreach($langs as $key => $lang)
                 <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]"  value="{{$key}}"> 
                 <label>{{ $lang }}</label>, 
                  @endforeach

                </div>
            </div>
```

To controller

```
public function Method(Request $request)
 {
    foreach((array)$request->input('foo') as $value){
    $file = 'la.txt';
    file_put_contents($file,$value );
    }

     return redirect()->route('profile');
     
 }
```

I want to display the value of all these three checkboxes, but only the data of one of them is displayed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKdit.png)

Comment: Unrelated fyi: the `for` attribute should point the related input element's `id` attribute

Comment: are you sure ``langs`` contains multiple values?

Comment: Yes, lang displays multiple values in label

Comment: I want multiple checkboxes to display all their data but only one value is displayed

Comment: Show us your form markup, from <form> to </form>

Comment: I want to do it so that the value of each of the checkboix is displayed

Comment: @dsdsasadsa correct this line `foreach ($request->input('foo') as $value) {` because `$request->input('foo')` has to be an array.

Comment: did you see all of checkbox data when you do `dd($request->all())` in your `controller` ? @dsdsasadsa

Comment: $request->input('foo') ,yes it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm - let me guess the issue, I think that you should return the values while you return back to the `profile` view. I think also the problem is not in the first load of the `profile` view, because you have to pass the `langs` array, but the issue happens when you click the checkboxes to store the data in the controller's method, so your code must be like so

```
public function storeData(Request $request)
 {
    foreach($request->input('foo') as $value){
        $file = 'la.txt';
        file_put_contents($file, $value);
    }

    $yourLangsArray = ["English", "Arabic"];

    return redirect()->route('profile')->with('langs', $yourLangsArray);  
 }
```